# How to determine which salt will precipitate from a solution containing multiple ions?

Tags: aqueous-solution, solubility, precipitation

I have a solution containing $0.2\:\mathrm{mol}$ of $\ce{Br^-}$ ions and $\ce{SO_4^2-}$ ions each.
Now if I add excess  $\ce{AgNO3}$ in this solution,
what will precipitate?
 $\ce{Ag2SO4}$ or $\ce{AgBr}$ or both?

And if I add just $0.2\:\mathrm{mol}$ of $\ce{AgNO3}$, what will precipitate?

(I don't want to calculate anything. Just wanted to know qualitatively that which compound precipitates.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to know that $K_\mathrm{sp}$ is used to determine the solubilities of sparingly soluble salts usually. You can get the values of $\ce{AgSO4,AgBr}$ and as $K_\mathrm{sp}=[\ce{Ag+}]^2[\ce{SO4^2-}]$ or $[\ce{Ag+}][\ce{Br-}]$. Now concentration of silver ion is constant so try calculating the other two anions and try comparing them.

Comment: So in excess both will precipitate eventually while in limited quantity, the one with lower Ksp will precipitate?

Comment: @pikachu i think you got it right.